# www-data access to log files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, sudo

I have a perl script that works fine with sudo and parses some logfiles at /var/log/ in Ubuntu 14. I want to show the program output on a webpage. My webpage code is very simple:

```
<html><body>
<h1>Under construction</h1>
<?php
exec ("perl /usr/local/bin/pflogsumm -d yesterday --smtpd_stats /var/log/mail/mail.log > parsed_mail_log.txt");
echo "<pre><p style='font-family:monospace;'>".nl2br(file_get_contents("parsed_mail_log.txt"))."</p></pre>";
?>
</body></html>
```

Without sudo, www-data (I guess that is the user when running the script) does not have permissions to access /var/log/mail/mail.log and does not count what I want. It outputs stuff, but only zeroes in place of the numbers I wanted to check.

My question is: what should be the "good" way of doing this?

Putting www-data in the root group so that it can read the log does not seem right.

Maybe I could invoke a script with sudo, inside such script invoke

```
sudo perl /usr/local/bin/pflogsumm -d yesterday...
```

And add the previous script to visudo so that www-data could run it with sudo without asking for authentication. Again, it seems it is not the "good" or the "right" way of doing it...

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not run a cron job (as root) every morning which executes

```
perl /usr/local/bin/pflogsumm -d yesterday --smtpd_stats /var/log/mail/mail.log > /path/to/parsed_mail_log.txt; chown www-data.www-data /path/to/parsed_mail_log.txt
```

(Assuming Ubuntu - use the appropriate apache owner on the chown), and then simply execute the second part in the browser

This would be much more secure (no executing scripts from the browser - less so from the command line), faster - it can preprocess the data overnight during off-peak times rather then real time and simpler.

Comment: Going with this, perfect for what I indend, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Good start is to see who is the owner and group of the log files (`ls -l /var/log/mail/mail.log`). Having them public readable is usually not a good idea. Then check what groups is `www-data` in: `groups www-data` should tell you.

You can either

- adjust the permissions on the file to be accessible by your user (probably not too clear)
- adjust the user groups to access these files (existing group of the file)

Using passwordless `sudo` in scripts is not a good idea.